# How to find body of a webpage using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I want to check if there is any content available on more than 500 webpages, using beautiful soup. This is the is script I wrote. It works, but somewhere it stops. If I fix the error it shows a different one. Below is the code I tried. I just want to be sure the page has a body. I'm unsure how to handle timeouts. Maybe the website needs more time.

method 1:

```
res  = requests.get(full_https_url, timeout=40)
soup  = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
elems = soup.select('body')
if elems == '':
    pass
else:
    print('body found')
```

method 2:

```
soup  = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
elems = soup.select('body')
if elems != '':
    print('body found')
else:
    pass
```

Comment: `soup.select()` doesn't return a string, it returns a list of all the matching elements.

Comment: If there's a timeout, `requests.get()` will raise an exception, it won't return an empty body. Use `try/except` to catch the error and skip the link.

Comment: @Barmar Can you please gave me an example. I tried every possible way I knew. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select()` returns a list, not a string, so it will always compare not equal to `''`, whether it's successful or not. Just test if the result is not empty.

Use `try/except` to catch the timeout error.

```
try:
    res = requests.get(full_https_url, timeout=40)
    soup  = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
    elems = soup.select('body')
    if elems:
        # do stuff
    else:
        print("No body in {full_https_url}")
except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
    print(f"Timeout on {full_https_url}, skipping")
```

Comment: I would argue that it would be better to wrap just the request in `try` and put the rest in  `finally` under a `res.ok` condition.

Comment: That's another way to go, but I think catching the specific condition in `except` is OK.

Comment: Yeah, that's not the issue. The issue is that isn't the only thing that can go wrong and you have a bunch of stuff that has little to do with the request in the `try`. Also you aren't testing if you even have a page `res.ok`. Just my opinion. I'm not trying to start a conflict.